# Mod Rewrite - Causing internal redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a RewriteRule as follows;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/$1 [L]
```

When someone enters in `http://dev/index.php` that actually the file that will be retrieved is `http://dev/test/index.php`.

However this seems to cause a load of internal redirects.

Any anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?test
```

...before the first `RewriteCond`.

The `[L]` flag on a rewrite rule (slightly counter-intuitively) causes the rewriting process to begin again again from the top. Your current rules will match on every iteration, and mod_rewrite will get into an infinite loop. Adding the above `RewriteCond` means that it will only match on the first iteration.

If you are running on Apache 2.3.9 or later, you could use the `[END]` flag on the rewrite rule instead of `[L]` - this will cause mod_rewrite to exit immediately and avoid the problem. This would actually be a better solution if it is available, as the above `RewriteCond` would prevent your rule from working for a page that legitimately begins with `test`.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's worked well. Quite obvious when you think of it but I'm a bit new to htaccess rewrites.

Comment: Yeah that is making sense too!